# how to return custom json in scalatra

Tags: json, scala, scalatra, scalatra-sbt

Scalatra Code:

```js
import org.scalatra._
import org.json4s.{DefaultFormats, Formats}
import org.scalatra.json._


class AppServlet extends AppStack with JacksonJsonSupport{
  protected implicit lazy val jsonFormats: Formats = DefaultFormats

  private def generateJSON():((String, String),(String, String)) = {
    val json = ("Firstname" -> "joe", "LastName" -> "cole")
    json
  }

  before() {
    contentType = formats("json")
  }

  get("/") {
    generateJSON
  }
}
```

I am trying to return simple json using scalatra framework and the output is something like this `{"_1":{"Firstname":"joe"},"_2":{"LastName":"cole"}}`. I dont need _1 or _2 to be printed. Please note i am not trying to return any objects. I just need to make my own json and then return it. It is not associated with any data model. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear to me what's the output you'd like to have

Comment: @mfirry i want the output to be lik this: `{Firstname:joe, LastName:cole}`

Comment: I can't find `AppStack` in any maven artifact - can you point the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import org.scalatra._
import org.json4s.{DefaultFormats, Formats}
import org.scalatra.json._
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._

class AppServlet extends AppStack with JacksonJsonSupport{
  protected implicit lazy val jsonFormats: Formats = DefaultFormats

  private def generateJSON():JObject = {
    val json = ("Firstname" -> "joe") ~ ("LastName" -> "cole")
    json
  }

  get("/") {
    generateJSON
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you create is a tuple of `(String, String)`, that's not surprising the output is like that. You should either create a case class, or, since you use `json4s`, return:

```
// don't forget this:
// import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
("Firstname" -> "joe") ~ ("LastName" -> "cole")
```